# Get next DIV from clicked DIV

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let next = this.parent.nextElementSibling.innerText
  console.log(next)
})
```

```html
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm wanting to get the text "test" from the above. So basically when the button is pressed, it'll jump to the parent, and then select the next div from what was clicked.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you use an arrow function as an event listener, you can't use `this` to get the event target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. In an arrow function, `this` is inherited from the calling context, it can't be set by the caller. So it won't be the event target. Use an event parameter `e`, and then use `e.currentTarget` to get the clicked element.
2. The correct property to get the parent is `parentElement`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let next = e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerText
  console.log(next)
})
```

```html
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, you should not use `event.target`

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  let next = evt.target.parent.nextElementSibling.innerText
  console.log(next)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I noticed you are using `this` to get the button element. Use of `this` is not possible in arrow functions, as `this` would become the window / global scope. So, I personally think it would be to convert this to a regular function.

Next, to get the parent element of an element, use the `.parentElement` property, not the `.parent` property.

With all these changes, here's some final code that seems to be working.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let next = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerText;
  console.log(next);
})
```

```html
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```

I hope this helps.